# SOQL - Comma Escape

Tags: soql

We have a field that contains "," (only the comma) in our Account object.

I am trying to run a extract query without success.

```
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CUS_FIELD__C = ',' --No records returned...eventhough there are quite a number of records
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CUS_FIELD__C = "," --Returns malformed query error
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CUS_FIELD__C = '\,' --Malform error
```

Can someone tell me how to do extract those records where the field is ","  (only the comma) ?

Comment: What type is this field? I tried the first form using a text field, seemed to work okay.

Comment: This is a formula field

Comment: Are you sure the formula field value doesn't have any space before or after the comma? If no, your first query should work for a formula field. I just tried it in my dev Org.

Comment: Account a = [SELECT ID,Postal_Address__c FROM Account WHERE Id = 'xxx'];

System.debug(a.Postal_address__c.length());

I choose an account which has just the comma in Postal_Address__c field and the length is returned as 1 as shown above

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT ID FROM ACCOUNT WHERE CUS_FIELD__C like '%,%'
```

Use Like clause in SOQL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm

Comment: That would not work...because the SOQL query that you have mentioned will return all records where "," (comma) is present..I believe the user is asking for a way to pull all the records where the ONLY data is just the comma